# Custom Gradle Test Task For Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, robolectric

**Problem**

I want to create a custom gradle test task to only run JUNIT tests and omit Robolectric tests. I am attempting to achieve this task by creating a new test annotation and omitting any tests that include that new annotation.

**Error**

JUNIT packages are not included when I run the the gradle task.

```
error: package android.test.suitebuilder.annotation does not exist
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;
```

**Details**

New Annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface RobolectricTest {
}
```

Gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url     'http://artifactory.ops.am1.qa.ext.bamgrid.com/artifactory/mobile-resources' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSDKVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"" + getDateAndTime() + "\""
        buildConfigField "String", "VERSION_BUILD", "\"" +     project["VERSION_BUILD"] + "\""
        versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
        versionName project.VERSION_NAME
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file(project.DEBUG_KEYSTORE)
            storePassword project.DEBUG_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias project.DEBUG_KEYSTORE_ALIAS
            keyPassword project.DEBUG_KEY_PASS
        }

        release {
            storeFile file(project.RELEASE_KEYSTORE)
            storePassword project.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias project.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_ALIAS
            keyPassword project.RELEASE_KEY_PASS
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res/',
                           'src/main/abc']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testCompile ('junit:junit:4.12')
    testCompile ('org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3')
    testCompile ('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0')
    testCompile ('org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0')
}

sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/resources']
    }
}

ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
    List urls = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath.collect {
        it.toURI().toURL()
    }
    return URLClassLoader.newInstance( urls as URL[] )
}    

/**
 *  Filters out files that have specific annotation
 * @param map - map of things to filter
 * @return - list of acceptable files after filter
 */
List annotationFilter( Map map ) {
   map.prefix = map?.prefix ?: '' // prefix: provide convenience for passing in annotation names

    ClassLoader loader = classLoader
    List result

    // filter with annotations
    if( !map.includes ) {
        result = map?.names
    } else {
        result = []
        map?.names.each { name ->
            Class klass = loader.loadClass( name )
            map?.includes.each { annotationName ->
                String fullName = map.prefix + annotationName
                Class annotation = loader.loadClass( fullName ).asSubclass( Annotation )
                if( !klass.isAnnotationPresent( annotation ) ) {
                    result << name
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if( result?.size() == 0 ) result = [ 'no.tests.to.run' ]
    return result
}

/**
 * Gradle task to run only robolectric tests.
 */
task unitTest( type: Test, description: 'Run all junit tests' ) {

    android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each { dir ->
        def buildDir = dir.getAbsolutePath().split('/')
        buildDir =  (buildDir[0..(buildDir.length - 4)] + ['build',     'classes', 'debug']).join('/')


        sourceSets.unitTest.compileClasspath += files(buildDir)
        sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath += files(buildDir)
    }

    testClassesDir = sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath

    doLast {
        println "Doing Last"
        List names = testClassNames()
        List filtered = annotationFilter( names: names, includes:   ['testUtils.RobolectricTest'] )
        println 'Running ' + filtered.size() + ' tests:\n' +     filtered*.toString()*.replaceAll('^','\t').join('\n')

       filter {
            setIncludePatterns( filtered as String[] )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Robolectric` tests are unit tests. What are you `really` trying to do?

Comment: 100% correct. Robolectric isn't run on our Linux servers. I want to cut them out and only do JUNIT.

Comment: `Robolectric isn't run on our Linux servers.` what? Robolectric runs fine on Linux. You are not asking the correct question. Do not cut out your testing efforts because you *think* they do not run on Linux.

Comment: Robolectric can't find AndroidManifest.xml when testing multidimensional flavor project on Ubuntu https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1936

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Custom Gradle Task To Only Run Specific Tests**

Building on @alphonzo79 answer, I was able to solve the issue.

The things to know

- Android gradle omits common testing features in gradle, like exclude and custom sourceSets.
- Retention and Target was not helpful. Only categories worked.
- You don't need a new build type, you only need to change the test option when compiling your own tasks.
- Don't use this - https://github.com/pkainulainen/gradle-examples/blob/master/integration-tests/build.gradle

The complete answer was to create a custom task that changed a flag for the android testOptions to excludeCategories.

[LINK](https://github.com/HIFILEO/ReactiveMvp/blob/master/app/build.gradle)

CODE

```
def integrationTests = false
```

...

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        useJUnit()
        if (integrationTests.toBoolean()) {
            println "Integration Tests Only for " + it.name
            options {
                excludeCategories 'com.example.reactivemvp.categories.UnitTest'
            }
        } else {
            println "Unit Tests Only for " + it.name
            options {
                excludeCategories 'com.example.reactivemvp.categories.IntegrationTest'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
task integrationTest(
    type: Test,
    description: 'Run integration tests only. Pass in \'-Pintegration=true\'',
    dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'clean'] ) {

    //Here for task completion, not actually used since sub task of testDebugUnitTest
    testClassesDir = file("src/integrationTest/java/");
    classpath = files("$System.env.ANDROID_HOME/sources/android-18")

    //
    //Turn on integration testing when argument exists and is true
    //
    if (project.hasProperty('integration')) {
        println integration
        if (integration == 'true') {
            integrationTests = true
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: how do you turn off the flag then?

Answer (score 5):

Not so much Robolectric-specific, but in regards to declaring a custom test task for Android with Gradle, I ran into a lot of trouble with this. As you found, all of the documentation and examples are using the Java plugin, but the Android plugin subverts most of it.

The only solution I found with the Android plugin is to create another build type, which will then result, under the hood, in the Android plugin creating new test tasks for me. Then I can easily modify the tasks.

Here is the relevant setup, which I keep in a `<rootProject>/gradle/test.gradle` file (This specific example uses Category annotation to filter unit tests into one task and integration tests into a separate task. For information on that part of it see https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Categories):

```
android {

    buildTypes {
        integration
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            useJUnit()

            if (it.name == 'testIntegrationUnitTest') {
                options {
                    excludeCategories 'com.example.categories.UnitTest'
                }
            } else {
                options {
                    excludeCategories 'com.example.categories.IntegrationTest'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the `<module>/build.gradle` file applies from this file with `apply from: "../gradle/test.gradle"`

This causes the `android` closure from the two files to be merged, results in a new `integration` build type, which in turn results in a new `testIntegrationUnitTest` task on the project in addition to the standard `testDebugUnitTest` and `testReleaseUnitTest` tasks.

But now, `testDebugUnitTest` runs only "real" unit tests, while `testIntegrationUnitTest` runs only integration tests.

Your mileage/implementation may vary. Once you're inside the `unitTest.all` closure you can do whatever manipulation you need to the options.

Comment: Is there something missing from this description? When I just add the integration buildType, nothing happens for the integration build.

Comment: This solution worked best for me - thanks. For completeness, and for the benefit of others, I have created a [test-categories](https://bitbucket.org/xni06/test-categories) repo so that I don't have to _cut'n paste_ things for each of my projects

Answer (score 3):

We can use the following configuration to exclude multiple tests by name:

```
def integrationTests = project.hasProperty('integrationTests') ? project.getProperty('integrationTests') : false //Default value false
android {
    //...
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
            returnDefaultValues = true
            all {                
                test {
                    filter {
                        if (integrationTests.toBoolean()) {
                            includeTestsMatching "*IntegrationTest"
                        } else {
                            includeTestsMatching "*UnitTest"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In command line:

```
gradlew test // Run only *UnitTest, Default value is false.
gradlew test -PintegrationTests=false // Run only *UnitTest
gradlew test -PintegrationTests=true // Run only *IntegrationTest
```

Comment: so you change the boolean in the build file, and then hit gradlew test? that is ridiculous

Comment: Hi @urSus, I updated the response in order to handle params, in that way you can define the behavior from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You said Robolectric can't find AndroidManifest.xml when testing multidimensional flavor project on Ubuntu

try to explicitly give the path to your manifest file in the @Config annotation

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, manifest = "../<path to>/AndroidManifest.xml")
```

Comment: The multidimensional flavor issue seemed to resolve itself with the upgraded version.